# Apache mod rewrite cookie

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

I would like to retrieve the value of a cookie and reuse this value in a variable in my vhost apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.test.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} user=john$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=USER:john] [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} user=jules$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=USER:jules] [L]

  Header set X-Hostname "%{USER}e"
</VirtualHost>
```

My cookie user can have several values, I try via the rewrite module but I don't get any value.

```
curl -L -v http://www.test.com/test.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.test.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.test.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 09 Mar 2018 18:22:09 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Fedora) PHP/7.1.8
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.8
< Set-Cookie: user=john; expires=Sun, 08-Apr-2018 18:22:09 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/
< X-Hostname: (null)
< Content-Length: 116
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance.
Rgs

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ - [E=USER:john] [L]` should be `RewriteRule ^ - [E=USER:john,L]` inside a singe square brackets.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I will try this

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe helps [https://serverfault.com/questions/499246/how-do-i-make-rewritecond-http-cookie-match-a-cookie-value-exactly](https://serverfault.com/questions/499246/how-do-i-make-rewritecond-http-cookie-match-a-cookie-value-exactly)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i will see it.